# Showing that Fourier pseudorandomness is insufficient for $k=4$ case (four arithmetic progressions)

Tags: co.combinatorics, fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

I wish to show that the Fourier pseudorandomness is insufficient to count the number of 4-term arithmetic progression.

1. Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ be a subset of a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ with density $|A| \leq \delta N$ ($0\leq \delta \leq 1$ and $N$ is very large).

For each $k\geq 1$ consider the number $$\{(n,r) \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}: n,n+r,\cdots,n+(k-1)r\in A\}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$ of $k$ term arithmetic progressions in $A$. Heuristically this expression should be close to $\delta^kN^2$.

2. We say that $A$ is *Fourier-pseudorandom* if we have $$\sup_{\xi \in \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}:\xi\neq0}|\hat{1}_A(\xi)|=o(1)$$ where $o(1)$ is the quantity that goes to zero as $N \to \infty$.

In the book higher order Fourier analysis by Professor Terence Tao, he provides two exercises **Ex 1.3.4** and **Ex 1.3.5** to show that the expression $(*)$, for k=4 is equal to $(c\delta^3+o(1))N^2$ as $N\to \infty$ i.e. the a Fourier-pseudorandom set can have  four-term arithmetic progression count significantly larger than $\delta^4N^2$.

Can someone please provide me a good source where I can find the solution to the above question or hints to solve the mentioned exercises in the above mentioned book? I have tried solving the exercises but I am unable to move forward and pretty sure that I am clueless.

If anyone is willing to mentor me / work closely with me to solve the question is also fine. I am ready to have discussions via zoom/google meet.

I have referred to the article by Professor W.T. Gowers where he shows two motivating examples to demonstrate the same. But my main motive here is to solve the exercises.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the introduction of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07598.pdf). It's still open whether a fourier uniform set can have way fewer 4APs than a random set.